# How to recover missing git commits?

Tags: git

I was playing around with a project in git and I appear to have lost months of commits.

Here is what I did:

`git checkout veryoldcommit`

I looked around in the files, found what I needed (didn't make any changes).

I then ran `git checkout master` to take me back to the latest commit.

I then wanted to delete only the very latest commit, so following [advice here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/927358/how-do-i-undo-the-most-recent-local-commits-in-git) I ran `git checkout HEAD-`.

This threw an error, I made a typo. I include here in case it is relevant.

I then ran `git checkout HEAD~` (with a tilde this time).

Now, I am stuck at `veryoldcommit` and I can't find how to access the newer commits. I'm terrified to touch anything 'cause I'm afraid I'll mess things up more.

I have months of work in that project, and it is not backed up to a remote repository.

What have I done? And, is it fixable?

Comment: `found what I needed` ... can you tell us _exactly_ what you are looking for/missing?

Comment: There was just a small amount of text that I only existed in an earlier commit.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it's fixable, that's the nice thing about git it doesn't destroy anything.
Try this:

```
git log --graph --all --format='%h %s%n        (%an, %ar)%d' --abbrev-commit --reflog
```

And look for the commit hash you want. You can create a new branch based on that commit with:

```
git checkout -b my-branch XXXXXX
```

or reset the current branch to point to that commit

```
git reset --hard XXXXXXX
```

good luck.

If you're paranoid make a copy of your `.git` directory somewhere else before doing this.

Comment: Good god that did it, you are a scholar and gentleman, a million times thank you.